# inserting a .swf or flash files in visual basic asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, flash

inserting a .swf or flash files in visual basic  asp.net 
give me coding sample or procedure or a link to inserting a flash files in my web form in vb asp.net

Comment: we cant do homework for you? Be descriptive about your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with VB or ASP.NET. Just `<embed>` the file in your page with HTML:

http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

[SWF Object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) works well for me for any language.